# Functions to combine elements of differents arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a problem here, with the arrays. So. I have 3 arrays:

```
const names = [Robert, Mark, Lindsay, Anna, Erin, Andrew]
const surnames = [Smith, Black, White, Lewis, Cooper, Hill]
const ages = [21, 14, 19, 28, 65, 31]
```

I must create 2 functions :

- On will give me a new array with the couples man-woman (like Robert-Anna / Erin-Mark etc.);
- And one must give a me a new array with the name, the surname and the age (like Robert Smith 21, Mark Black 14, etc.).

So, what I think for the first function was to do this randomly:

```
function getElementFromArray(arr)  {
    const min = 0;
    const max = (arr.length);
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
    return arr[randIndex];
}

const boyArray = Array("Robert", "Mark", "Andrew");
const boy = getElementFromArray(boyArray);
const girlArray = Array("Erin", "Anna", "Lindsay");
const girl = getElementFromArray(girlArray);
const getPair = [boy + girl];
```

But this is not a function, so I must to transform this into a function. And this thing gives me only one couple of Man+Woman, but i need 3 couples that must to be written in an Array form.

For the second function, i really don't now how to write it. Thinked about something like:

```
const nameSurnameAge = [names.slice (0, 1) + surnames.slice (0, 1) + ages.slice (0, 1)] + [names.slice (1, 2) + surnames.slice (1, 2) + ages.slice (1, 2)]
```

But again: this is not a function (and i need to transform this thing into a function) and it's very-very long.

Can somebody help me please?
Thank You!

Comment: Is this for a test/homework? If not why not structure your data to be more meaningful in the first place so you don't have to jump through these hoops?

Comment: It's for a test Andy

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays of men and women.  Assuming there are an equal number of men and women.

```js
const names = ["Robert", "Mark", "Lindsay", "Anna", "Erin", "Andrew"]
const surnames = ["Smith", "Black", "White", "Lewis", "Cooper", "Hill"]
const ages = [21, 14, 19, 28, 65, 31]
const genders = ["M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M"]

var arrNew = [];
var people = [];


function fnBuildNewArray(){
for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
  
    people[i] = {
        name: names[i],
        surname: surnames[i],
        age: ages[i],
        gender: genders[i],
        partner: "single"
    };
  
    arrNew[i] = people[i]["name"]+" "+people[i]["surname"]+" is "+people[i]["age"];
  
}
}

function fnBuildCouples(){
   var iMen = [];
   var iWomen = [];
 
   var m=0;
   var w=0;
  
  // collect men and woman
  for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    if(people[i]["gender"]=="M"){
      iMen[m] = i;
      m++;
    }
    else
    {
      iWomen[w] = i;
      w++;
    }
  }
  
  // This is where the magic happens

  // Shuffle the Women
      
      let iWomenshuffled = iWomen
      .map(value => ({ value, sort: Math.random() }))
      .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
      .map(({ value }) => value);
      
  
   var offset=0;

  // assign the partners
  for (var i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    if(people[i]["gender"]=="M"){
      var z = iWomenshuffled[offset];
      people[i]["partner"] = people[z]["name"];
      people[z]["partner"] = people[i]["name"]
      offset++;
    }
  }
   
  
}
  

function fnProcess(){
  
     
  fnBuildNewArray();
  
  fnBuildCouples();
   
   
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arrNew));
 console.log(JSON.stringify(people));
 
 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fnProcess()">Process</button>
```